# Is it possible to copy/paste all rows with #N/A without Filtering Columns?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm curious if it's possible to copy all rows with an #N/A (Formula error) which appears in multiple columns on one sheet (they change field numbers spreadsheet to spreadsheet) and then paste them into another?

What I'm currently using for code requires a specific column (Field 44 in this example) to be selected. Since the columns with #N/A aren't static I'm looking for a way to copy all rows that have the #N/A without filtering. Is this possible or is there no way around the field requirements?

```
Sheets("Fall 2016").Select
Range("$A$2:$CU$" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=44, Criteria1:="#N/A"
Range("$A$3:$CU$" & lrow).Copy

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SpecialCells to find all of the errors returned from formulas.

```
dim lrow as long, erng as range

with workSheets("Fall 2016")

    lrow = 'get lrow here

    on error resume next
    set erng = .range("A2:CU" & lrow).specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    on error goto 0

    if not erng is nothing then
        intersect(.range("A:CU"), erng.entirerow).copy
        workSheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    end if


end with
```